# if such counter example exists for Lehmer's totient problem could we prove that there are infinity of them or just finitely?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, counterexamples

I asked this question one month Ago in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704941/156150) but no answer for existence of argument which show if such counter example exists we would have infinity of them or just finitely many examples

[Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) asks whether there is any composite number $n$ such that Euler's totient function $φ(n)$ divides $n − 1$. which it is unsolved problem or we may reformulate that question as : if $φ(n)$ divides $n − 1$ then $n$ must be a prime , Now my question here is :if a such counter example exists for  Lehmer's totient problem  could we prove that  there are infinity of them or just finitely of them ?